# Python Digitize continuous variable input data into discrete variable (bins) where the distribution is Normal Gaussian

Tags: python, gaussian

I have a time-series of various data, (continuous variable), that I want to discretize. Now, my understanding is that the 'bin', digitize function of python groups them linearly along the max/min range.

However, I would like to create the bin values such that the bin-values group the underlying-data distribution in a Normal-gaussian distribution. How can I adapt my simplistic code below to do that?

```
data_X = [x1, x2, x3,  ...., xi] 

data_Y = [y1, y2, y3, ....., yi]

bins_ = np.interp(np.linspace(0, len(data_X), bins), np.arange(len(data_X)), np.sort(data_X)) 

pred_ = np.digitize(data_X, bins_)
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.digitize(data_X, bins)` groups the values according to the bin edges that you give it with `bins`.
If you use

```
bins = np.linspace(data_X.min(), data_X.max(), num=10)
```

you will get linear bin edges. This leads to the bins being filled in a gaussian manner (middle bins have more values, outer bins less), but based on the min/max in your data.

Instead you could calculate bin edges based on a known distribution or based on the data.
For example, you could create bin edges based on a normal distribution with standard deviation `sigma` around zero and include `sds` standard deviations in the bins:

```
sds = 3
bins = np.concatenate( ([data_X.min()], np.linspace(-sds*sigma, sds*sigma, sds*2+1), [data_X.max()] ) )
```

The data_X.min/max are for under-/overflow. Entirely data-driven bins following your input function would look like this:

```
bins = np.quantile(data_X, np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
```

With all of these bins you can call `np.digitize(data_X, bins)` and obtain the given distribution.